# Eclipse CDT poor indexing and code completion/analysis

Tags: c++, eclipse, intellisense, code-analysis, eclipse-cdt

I'm having several headaches trying to work in Eclipse for C++ development.

The IDE persistently shows Errors and Warnings in the Problems pane, even after they have been solved - only a right-click->"Delete" seems to clear them.  Even then, a few will pop back up after a compile, which is probably related to the second issue...

My codebase is rather small (two projects, one for unit tests, one for a small library I'm developing), though I do make use of basic C++ templating. However, Eclipse largely fails to code complete for included libraries, files in my own workspace but separate projects, and even occasionally files within the same project.

I've tried rebuilding the index on my projects and fiddled with a few settings, but to no avail. In the past I have used Visual C++, with it's wonderful Intellisense, but I'm running Linux at the moment and want an IDE that can (eventually) handle multiple languages and toolchains - for which Eclipse excels.

I've tried googling but found no real help.  Does anyone out there have any hints for tweaking Eclipse CDT for better code completion/analysis?  Or is this just the nature of non-Visual Studio development?